# Adding datatable to laravel mix files

Tags: laravel, npm, datatables, laravel-mix

I have installed `datatables` with npm by help of [this doc](https://datatables.net/download/npm#NPM-package-installation), now I'm not sure how I can add datatables css and js files to my `app.css` and `app.js`

#### Downloaded files by NPM

[image: one]

## Code

my `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

    //laravel default to make app.css and app.js
    // I want add Datatables to these files
    mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

    //my template files
    mix.combine([
       'public/theme/primary/js/jquery.min.js',
       'public/theme/primary/js/popper.min.js',
       'public/theme/primary/js/bootstrap.min.js',
       'public/theme/primary/js/uza.bundle.js',
       'public/theme/primary/js/default-assets/active.js'
    ], 'public/js/combined.js');
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved

I added this code to my `bootstrap.js` under `require('bootstrap');`

```
 require( '../../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js' );
 require( '../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js' );
```

and then added styles to my `app.scss`

```
@import '~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css';
```

Everything works perfectly now.
Hope it help others.

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple scripts and styles you can do it this way:

```
mix.scripts([
   'node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js',
   'resources/js/app.js'
])
.styles([
   'node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css',
   'resources/sass/app.scss'
]);
```

This by default should create `all.js` and `all.css` files in the respective `js` and `css` public folders.

Comment: that was returning error, however i figured it out and shared the solution, thanks,